# Filtering a ndarray in numpy

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a ndarray and I want to filter out a particular value of it. My array is:

```
arr = np.array([
   [1., 6., 1.],
   [1., 7., 0.],
   [1., 8., 0.],
   [3., 5., 1.],
   [5., 1., 1.],
   [5., 2., 2.],
   [6., 1., 1.],
   [6., 2., 2.],
   [6., 7., 3.],
   [6., 8., 0.]
])
```

I want to filter out `[6., 1., 1.]`. So I have tried:

```
arr[arr != [6., 1., 1.]]
```

and I got:

```
array([1., 6., 1., 7., 0., 1., 8., 0., 3., 5., 5., 5., 2., 2., 2., 2., 7.,
   3., 8., 0.])
```

which is not what I want (and also destroyed the previous structure of the array). I have also tried:

```
arr[arr[:] != [6., 1., 1.]]
```

but I got the same output as before.

P.S.: I know I can delete an element by its index, but I don't want to do that. I want to check for the particular element.

P.P.S.: For 1-d arrays my method works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're very close. The boolean array you get tells you how many elements match in each row. You need to make sure that all the elements in a row match to delete it, or that any of the elements don't match to keep it:

```
arr[(arr != [6, 1, 1]).any(axis=1)]
```

You can also write it as

```
arr[~(arr == [6, 1, 1]).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But with what you wrote, I get:

array([[1., 7., 0.],
       [1., 8., 0.],
       [5., 2., 2.]])

and I was looking for:

array([[1., 6., 1.],
       [1., 7., 0.],
       [1., 8., 0.],
       [3., 5., 1.],
       [5., 1., 1.],
       [5., 2., 2.],
       [6., 2., 2.],
       [6., 7., 3.],
       [6., 8., 0.]])

Comment: I just looked up the documentation for it. I realized that if you change "all" to "any", I get what I want. Thank you for your reply anyways!

Comment: @PedroHenrique. Of course. This is what happens when I don't test my code late at night. Please see the update.